# VBA Loops Using Subtraction

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I'm trying to develop a 'for loop' macro that will calculate the duration between two dates in adjacent columns.

My current code:

```
Sub Enter_Formulas()

FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Counts # of rows in the data set

For x = 5 To FinalRow

Cells(x, 10).Formula = "=I5-H5"

End Sub
```

---

This will accurately return the difference between I5 & H5, but I want the formula to flow down the columns. (i.e. the next row should calculate I6 - H6 and then I7-I8.. and so on and so forth)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Just put the formula in your first cell, then double click on the small green box in the bottom right hand corner of the cell. Excel will auto-populate the formula all the way down.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this macros will be supporting a userform that will constantly be updating. I don't want the end consumer to refresh each time they enter new data.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using a loop, you can autofill the whole range in one go:

```
Sub Enter_Formulas()

FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Counts # of rows in the data set

Range(Cells(5, 10).address, Cells(FinalRow, 10).address).Formula = "=I5-H5"

End Sub
```

However, if you must use a loop then try this:

```
For x = 5 to FinalRow
Cells(x,10).Formula = "=" & Cells(x,9).Address & "-" & Cells(x,8).Address
Next x
```

That way by concatenating cell addresses relying on x, they will also increment by one row each time.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Could you please explain the '.address' portion of the code? I tried something similar to this where I defined the formula "=I5-H5" but it carried the same values down the column. Is the range portion of this calculation the trigger for row reference?

Comment: Yeah, a single cell formula set across a specified Range will fill it as if you placed it in one cell then drag-filled it manually on the worksheet. The Address part of a Cells reference will specify the Address as opposed to the value in the cell at that address (e.g. `Cells(1,1).Address` gives `A1` but `Cells(1,1).Value` gives whatever value is IN cell A1. You can set a whole range as above using cells separated with a comma: `Range(Cells(1,1).Address, Cells(1,5).Address)` gives `Range(A1:A5)` - you should google it, it probably explains it better than I can :D

Comment: `Range(Cells(5, 10).address, Cells(FinalRow, 10).address).Formula = "=I5-H5"` would be better written as `Range(Cells(5, 10), Cells(FinalRow, 10)).Formula = "=I5-H5"` - there's no point in obtaining a cell's address when the syntax accepts the cell itself as a parameter.  (And, I suspect, when an address is passed as the parameter, the first thing that has to happen is it has to create a reference to the cell at that address - so you are probably just adding work.)

Comment: jamheadart - Thank you so much for the help! Excellent advice and explanation

Comment: YowE3K - it can be written that way but I've developed a habit of specifying .Address vs .Value2 since I often need both, and end up concatenating both in work to get particular strings, so find it good practice to specify which I'm using for code revision.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this, if you must use a loop (and I usually would not), by using the R1C1 form of addressing:

```
For X = 5 To FinalRow
    Cells(X, 10).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"
Next X
```

And if your worksheet is using the A1 reference style, this will get translated appropriately.